# Rapid succession of taps interpreted as a single moving touch event? (tested on Nexus 10)

Tags: android, hardware, android-hardware, nexus-7, nexus-10

I'm developing an Android application in which a user may be rapidly tapping with multiple fingers. Initial testing on the Nexus 10 tablet reveals that a tap rapidly followed by another tap nearby is often interpreted as a single touch-and-slide motion, with both touch points attributed to a single pointer index. This appears to be a hardware issue, or at least an issue with some low-level touch processing in Android.

Similarly, I've seen tapping with two fingers placed together simultaneously being interpreted as a single touch from one large finger.

Has anyone experienced any similar difficulty with rapid pairs of touches being mistakenly interpreted as a single touch? I'm hoping that someone has some clever workarounds, or ways to cleverly infer that a moving touch may actually be coming from a single touch?

To be clear, my observations are based on visualizing touches by turning on "Pointer Location" from the developer settings, and so are independent of my application.